# Why is it that when you break a brick it hurts less than when you don't break the brick?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, momentum, conservation-laws, collision

Why is it that when you break a brick it hurts less than when you don't break the brick?

Consider the brick has a maximum force it can endure $F_\text{max}$. If you hit the brick and it doesn't break the impact force is less than $F_\text{max}$, and you feel a reactionary force equal to the impact force you exerted on the brick. However, if you hit the brick and it does break, the reactionary force should be equal to $F_\text{max}$, but $F_\text{max}$ is still larger than the force you used to hit the brick initially, but it did not break. Hence, you should still feel a larger force and more pain, right?

Or maybe the reactionary force of the broken brick is somehow less than the impact force?

Imagine you are standing on thin ice which is about to break. On solid ground, according to Newton's Third Law, if you jump you exert a force on the ground and the ground exerts an opposite force which accelerates you upwards. However, if you try to jump up from thin ice, you can't because the ice breaks as you are exerting more force than your body weight. However the fact that you can't jump up means the ice isn't applying an opposite force of equal magnitude. Does this mean if the ice breaks, the reactionary force exerted on you is less than the impact force you exerted on the ice?

Comment: My confusion is if action force=reaction force, then if you hit a brick with a larger force it should still hit back with the same large force, then why is it less painful?

Answer (score 1):

When your hand initially contacts the brick it has an initial kinetic energy. The brick then either stops your hand eliminating the kinetic energy or slows it down reducing iis kinetic energy. In either case the loss in you hands kinetic energy will equal the work done by the brick on your hand, or

$$\Delta KE=F_{ave}d$$

Where $F_{ave}$ equals the average impact force on your hand and $d$ is the distance your hand moves through the brick. For a given change in kinetic energy $d$ is greater if you break the brick than if you don’t making the average impact force less.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I feel like you could go further, as a unbroken brick means a larger $\Delta KE$ as well as a smaller $d$. But a small caveat to mention is that this analysis neglects the forces also exerted by the body on the hand during the collision.

Comment: Also this doesn't seem to address the concern of the maximum force needed to break the brick. I suppose your assumption is that there is a correspondence between average force and pain, but is this necessarily true? Are there other factors that determine pain/damage to the hand? Would the same average force applied over a different distance/time have the same pain? I'm not sure how to validate/invalidate this.

Comment: Sure, I’m sure I could have elaborated further, but answered on my mobile device which can be a pain. I just wanted to point out the shorter the stopping distance the greater the impact force, all else being equal.